# защита desktop-приложения на java

Tags: java, tomcat, desktop

Есть старый проект(xul, tomcat 5, jdk 1.5, hibernate, firebird и т.д. ), в котором дополнительный функционал устанавливается только тем клиентам, рег.номер которых занесен в поле типа static, то есть в константу.

Когда клиент устанавливает на свой компьютер клиентскую часть и серверную, то он при установке указывает свой регистрационный номер и этот номер устанавливается в специальную таблицу.
 При запуске приложения идет сверка по рег.номеру в таблице и по списку номеров, 
установленных через дефис, в константаном поле. Если в этом поле найден клиент и найдено сооветсвие в таблице, тогда клиенту позволяется работать с доп.функционалом.

Опасаются что клиент может найти класс, декомпилирует, который содержит константу с допустимыми рег.номерами, подправит данный класс и снова скомпилирует.

приложение устанавливается на windows.

Как можно защитить приложение от взлома?

Comment: Вариант в лоб - шифровать важные классы с ключом, который зависит от серийного номера.

Comment: можете подсказать где это может быть описано, что-то вроде `быстрый старт`